# Do numbers of this form have a name?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$$48625 = 4^{5} + 8^{2} + 6^{6} + 2^{8} + 5^{4}$$

Notice that the digits of the number are in digit order, while the exponents are the digits of the number in reverse order.

Do numbers of this form have a name?

Comment: This is a fun question! +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are "tabulated" at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A048341). I use the quotes because there are only two of them, the other one being $397612$ (I don't count $1$). No name is given at that site, but there are some links there that you might follow up. If you find anything, be sure to let us know.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there might possibly be only one, so at least there is another example and some things to investigate. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Inverted Munchausen numbers in base 10.

Comment: Can you also site a reference